# How to make menu by using Master Page with jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

nowadays i m  making one mvc project and  i use master page i wanna make  menu with  items have active preferences i  used

      $(document).ready(function() {   //document

```
      $('#tabMenu > li').click(function() {  //clik


          if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {      //if


              $('#tabMenu > li').removeClass('active');

              /  
              $(this).addClass('active');




          }  //endif

      } //click
```

);
      } //document
      );
and  html menus/*
/*ul id="tabMenu">
     <%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%>
     <%= Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%>

```
</ul>*/
```

it is  working  but just 1 second becoz  master  page  load its menu and so how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear...

The following code works... Maybe this helps?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #tabMenu li        {display:block;float:left;background-color:green;}
    #tabMenu li a      {color:white;}
    #tabMenu li.active {background-color:blue;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tabMenu > li').click(function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $('#tabMenu > li').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });    
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="tabMenu">
            <li><a href="#">MenuItem</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MenuItem</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MenuItem</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```