# Appearance of a selected menu item in master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web application with one master page that contains the menu, and several .aspx pages. The menu is something like https://jsfiddle.net/96bd8y0z/

```
<style>
     a, a:visited { color:black }
     a.link.active { color:blue; }
<style>

<script>
     $(function () {
        $('a.link').click(function () {
        $('a.link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        });
     });
```

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="link active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

It works fine in the fiddle: When you select one of the links in the menu, its appearance changes, in the fiddle from black to blue. But when I try to apply this scheme in my web application, the link that I select (say: 'News') becomes blue for a second, the hyperlink page ('News') is loaded, 'News' becomes black again, and the the menu entry 'Home' becomes blue again.

I can understand that this happens because the master page section is re-loaded but I don't know how to solve it.

Is there a way to keep the selected option active (i.e. keep 'News' blue)?

I believe this question is similar to [How to make menu by using Master Page with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938676/how-to-make-menu-by-using-master-page-with-jquery), but the user that answered this question found this question unclear and his answer did not solve it for me.

Comment: You want to place that code in the header page that is being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

It probably would be better to do it in the back-end: keep a variable in aspx that specifies in which page you are, and then in the master page, compare that variable for each menu, and add the "active" class only to the one that you want.

If you want to do it with JavaScript, you could do one thing: when the link is clicked, save the index of the menu element, then when the page is reloaded, mark that element as the active one.

Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.link').click(function() {
        $('a.link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        // save the index for later (notice it's the index of the li, not the a)
        localStorage.setItem("active", $(this).parent().index());
    });

    // read the previous index or initialize to the first one if first time
    var active = localStorage.getItem("active") ? localStorage.getItem("active") : 0;
    // add the active class to the element
    $("ul li:nth-child(" + (parseInt(active)+1) +") a").addClass("active");
});
```

You can see it working on this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/96bd8y0z/6/ (rerun or reload the page to see how the blue link remains). But again, doing it in the back-end would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, menu is re-rendered on each page request, it`s evident that all  classes added on previous page opening would disappear.

So, in order to make needed menu item selected, there should be a check for every link: if it`s href attribute is equal to the route of the loaded page, then add "active" class to it.

Meanwhile, it`s a bad practice to do it with javascript, better do it while building template. But if it has to be done with js, you probably can do something like this (using jquery for links selection):

```
$(function() {
    var links = $('.link');

    for (var i = links.length; i--;) {
        var _this = $(links[i]);

        if (document.URL.split('http://site-domain.net')[1] == _this.attr('href')) {
            $('.link').removeClass('active');
            _this.addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the fiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/96bd8y0z/4/